# MYSQL Temporary table space

Tags: mysql

I am running this query:

```
select CONCAT("2000",page_hits.email_id) as campaign_code ,
       page_hits.url,
       count(page_hits.url) as clicks, 
       count(page_hits.url) / ( SELECT read_count 
                                FROM emails 
                                WHERE emails.id = page_hits.email_id ) as clicks_percent
from page_hits 
where page_hits.email_id
group by page_hits.email_id,
      page_hits.url
```

and have recently started getting the error

```
Error Code: 1114. The table '/rdsdbdata/tmp/#sql6061_11566_91' is full
```

MYSQL 8.0.25
Database size is 248GB total and the space on the server is 1TB.
8cpu with 64GB ram

Can I rewrite this to be better?  I can't see why it fails now when it worked before.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/full-table.html#:~:text=If%20a%20table%2Dfull%20error,not%20by%20MySQL%20internal%20limits.

Comment: Move subquery to FROM.

Comment: I'm surprised you never get a "division by zero" error. There has to be a page_hits record for each email. You could rewrite this query as a simple JOIN between two tables, avoiding the subquery.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware how?

Comment: Well, I made an attempt. See: [SQL-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w2XUfGjEq9DrikS7LzPaG3/0). But, as you can see, there's a difference between what the JOIN query gets and what your query gets. This difference makes perfect sense to me, but it might not be what you want. The problem is, I do understand more-or-less, what the query does, but I don't understand your intentions with it. There's no description in the question of what the query is suppose to do. That's why I leave it here, and don't try to make both queries have exactly the same result.

Comment: You are a very nice person.  Thank you for taking the time out to take a look at this.  I was able to successfully use your join .  However I notice an interesting thing.  When i omit the second group by it works in either case.